# Having error to start Equinox on OSGi

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

While trying to start Equinox on OSGi to get the osgi prompt I am getting and error like

```
!SESSION 2013-07-23 12:18:46.215 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -console

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-07-23 12:18:46.574
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that 
    the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at   

                                                                                               org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:   74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:152)
```

The entry in my config.ini file is as follows:

```
osgi.bundles=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20111215-1210.jar@start,       
file:\org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar@start, 
file:\org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705.jar@start, 
file:\org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar@start
```

Can anyone please suggest some solution to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, why do you want to have the Equinox console AND the gogo shell?

It seems you're using the Equinox launcher and this launcher requires an Application service to be present, which I recall is very Eclipse specific. If you experiment with Equinox I would not use this launcher. Either use bndtools or make your own launcher (which is quite simple, look at the Apache Felix: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html (this works exactly the same for Equinox).

In general, Apache Felix's framework and bundles work much easier to get started with on this level.